# jQuery - can't send value to function

Tags: jquery

I want to send data to a function after the default value of an input field is changed.

```
function change_pos(position, new_pos) {
    $.post(iloc, {a:"change_pos", position:position, new_pos:new_pos}, function(d){
        window.location = "[@HTTP_ADDR]/cms/gallery";
    });
}

<input type=\"text\" value=\"{$row['POSITION']}\" onchange=\"change_pos('{$row['POSITION']}', this)\" />
```

The idea is to send the current and "new" positions. But the function doesn't accept them.
Note: PHP is fine! jQuery is the problem!

Comment: `this` mapped to `new_pos` argument is input field itself and not the value in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `this` in `onchange` event with `this.value`

Answer (score 0):

`this` mapped to `new_pos` argument of `change_pos()` is input field itself and not the value in it. Try getting value with `this.value` in `onchange`